# How can I get a list of the patches I submitted for issues on drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site

How can I get a list of the patches I submitted for issues on drupal.org?

I can see the list of my posts, but I need only those with a patch.

Comment: Don't think so you get the list of patches you applied in drupal.org, only you can see commits, issues, posts

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens  I have applied patches but not on my website,I have applied them to drupal projects

Comment: I just mean "How can I get all the patches list which I have applied"

Comment: I think submitted applies here, not applied. It's a minor issue, though, and no point discussing that, as it's clear enough what OP means.

Answer (score 0):

If you contributed patches, they will be credited to you. In that case, on your profile, you will see the ones credited to you in the past 3 months. In my case, I see the following.

> [image: screenshot]

Keep in mind that sometimes you participate in an issue without contributing patches, and you get credited for participating.

Unfortunately, there isn't a page with all the credited issues for all the projects, but if you have a list of the projects to which you contributed patches, you can get the list of the credited issues for that project by looking at `https://www.drupal.org/u/<username>/issue-credits/<project-id>`, where `<username>` is the username on drupal.org (in my case, kiamlaluno) and `<project-id>` is the ID for the project (for example, 3060 for Drupal core). So, if I would want to look to all the patched I submitted for Drupal core, I would look at https://www.drupal.org/u/kiamlaluno/issue-credits/3060.

It seems that the list of credited patches has been created on 2015, so you would not get any credited patch before that year.

Comment: ok...Any reason there is no direct list of users patches